# Combining 2D/3D gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

In gnuplot, by combining *splot* and *contour* commands it is possible to obtain a plot with 3d figure and a 2d figure at bottom (or top) face of the box. However, I wonder if would be possible to do the same but instead of 2d contours replace this with external 2d “data"...?

Answer (score 1):

Certainly.  Every 2D plot is also a 3D plot with constant Z coordinate.  While it is true that gnuplot supports some 2D plot styles (e.g. histogram) that have no 3D equivalent, the common styles involving points, lines, vectors, and labels exist in both 2D and 3D.  So in many cases the answer to your question is that if you want to position a 2D plot such as

```
 plot "data" using 1:2 with linespoints
```

on the bottom face of a 3D unit cube, i.e. the xy-plane at z=0, you can replace it with

```
 splot "data" using 1:2:(0) with linespoints
```

Comment: Thank you Ethan! Certainly it works. Now, I realize that plot with circles is not available in splot command, which is reasonable in general, but in this case it would be useful to show that I want.

Comment: `splot with circles` will be supported in version 5.4